# Show two items in one row in each loop using Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have some issue with Each loop in Jade. I have to show 2 items in the row, but it doesn't work for me.

```
each item,i in feature.items 
    .col-mb-8.col-tb-12.col-dt-6
        h4.b--feature__title!=item.title
        p.b--feature__text!=item.text
```

and I need to add .col-group before odd items. Is it possible with Jade? Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I finally find solution, that work for me

```
    each  item,i in feature.items
        - if (i.substr(4)%2) {
            | <div class='col-group'>
        - }
            .col-mb-8.col-tb-12.col-dt-6
                h4.b--feature__title!=item.title
                p.b--feature__text!=item.text
        - if (i.substr(4)%2 == 0)  {
            | </div>
        - }
```

and this render to

```
<div class="col-group">
  <div class="col-mb-8 col-tb-12 col-dt-6">
    <h4 class="b--feature__title">heade</h4>
    <p class="b--feature__text">text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-mb-8 col-tb-12 col-dt-6">
    <h4 class="b--feature__title">heade</h4>
    <p class="b--feature__text">text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-group">
  <div class="col-mb-8 col-tb-12 col-dt-6">
    <h4 class="b--feature__title">heade</h4>
    <p class="b--feature__text">text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-mb-8 col-tb-12 col-dt-6">
    <h4 class="b--feature__title">heade</h4>
    <p class="b--feature__text">text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to have different output for even and odd elements:

```
each item,i in feature.items 
    - if (i % 2) {
    .col-mb-8.col-tb-12.col-dt-6
        h4.b--feature__title!=item.title
        p.b--feature__text!=item.text
    - } else {
    .col-mb-8.col-tb-12.col-dt-6
        h4.b--feature__title!=item.title
        p.b--feature__text!=item.text
    - }
```

Just make the changes that you need to the tags or classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I made some change in your code, but it isn't work for me, because I need to add some kind of wrap to first and second element 
`<div class='wrap'>
    <div>col-mb-8</div>
   <div>col-mb-8</div>
</div>
`
How can I do something like this?

Comment: @elektrobober It was just an example with the same code that you posted for both even and odd elements. I wrote that you need to make the changes that you need to the tags or classes. You can put whatever you need there. If this answer helped you then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157646).